# Vue leayk custom event being registered by multiple components

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, dom-events

I have a custom event which is added via

```js
...
mounted() {
  window.addEventListener(...)
},
...
```

and am using `event.stop.prevent` but whereever I have those statements the events are registered, event when I do not want them to.

https://codesandbox.io/s/kw64lpk3y5

In the sandbox the event is defined in `highlighter.vue`
Highlighting a line of text should only add one sub array, but it is always registering 4...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So each component mounted adds an event to the "eventarray".

One possibility is to add this event to the component itself

or to filter by `e.target`

like so:
[`this.$el.addEventListener`](https://codesandbox.io/s/z3ormjxyx4)

Comment: how would I do that?  I tried moving the `addEventListener` to created.

Comment: i updated this answer: this.$el.addEventListener helps

Comment: yes, but then it must be defined in the `mounted` loop, rather than `created`

Comment: i am confused now, is it an issue if it is in mounted?

Comment: No, `this.$el` doesn't exist until mounted. In theory a component could exist, but be mounted several times, so normally that is added in the `created` hook, rather than mounted

Comment: ah ok now i get your thought process ^^